# Mule HTTP responseTimeout

Tags: mule, mule-component, mulesoft

I am using ws-consumer with http-request-config as below in MUle 3.8.4 api.

```
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration" responseTimeout="1000"/>
...
<ws:consumer-config name="Web_Service_Consumer" connectorConfig="HTTP_Request_Configuration" wsdlLocation="myws.wsdl" service="MyWebServiceService" port="MyWebServicePort" serviceAddress="http://localhost:8081/"/>;
```

ResponseTimeout is set at 1 second. It works for 90% of the calls to this ws (throws Timeout if ws takes more than 1 sec to respond).  But for 10% of the time it does not throw the error when the ws takes more than a second to return the response. For these 10% of time, Mule is waiting until the ws responds back or global timeout expires (which is set to 10 sec). I want Timeout on this ws call to be 1 sec (there are other service calls in the api which should follow 10 sec timeout).

Could you please let me know what is happening during this 10% of the calls not throwing the Timeouts.

Comment: Mule 3.8.4 is an older version that is going to end of life later this year. Would it be possible to test with a newer Mule 3.x version to see if some fix helps with this issue? The latest release is 3.9.4.

Comment: @aled , No , my organization dont have plans to upgrade right now.

Comment: Can you reproduce it with a different version in Studio?